# R: insert rows at specific places in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I can't seem to find an example to help me solve a particular problem in R. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
tmp = data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B",2), rep("C",6)), value = rnorm(13))
```

In reality I have thousands of columns and rows with many different values for group. The rows in the data frame are ordered by group.

I'd like to insert a new row above the first occurrence of each group. I'd also like for these new rows to only contain a value (the same value) in the first column (although I can make do if columns 2:ncol(tmp) contain NAs). Using the example data frame above, the end result should look like this:

```
   group      value
   GROUP
   A          -1.7596279
   A          -0.8273928
   A          -0.3515738
   A          -0.7547999
   A           0.5700747
   GROUP
   B          -1.9676482
   B           0.3996858
   GROUP
   C           0.1047832
   C           0.5903711
   C          -1.3687259
   C           0.3688415
   C           1.3674403
   C           0.8880089
```

Is there a way to do this? I can come up with a list of rows containing the first instance of each group. I was originally thinking that I could use this information to define where new rows should be inserted, but not sure if this is the best way to go.

Comment: It is of course possible, but it sounds like a really bad idea. What would you like to achieve in the end?

Comment: @AEF I am formatting my data for import to a non-R based program.

Comment: Ah, ok, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a function that does what you want it to do:

```
addEmptyRows <- function(D)
{
  output <- tmp
  i <- 1
  while (i < NROW(output)) {
    if(output$group[i] != output$group[i+1])
    {
      output <- rbind(output[1:i,],c("GROUP","NA"),output[(i+1):NROW(output),])
      i <- i+1
    }
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(rbind(c("GROUP","NA"),output))
}
```

If you apply this function to your dataframe:

```
addEmptyRows(tmp)
```

It gives you the desired dataframe. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
tmp <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B",2), rep("C",6)), value = rnorm(13))

divider <- data.frame(group = "GROUP", value = NA)

do.call(rbind, unlist(lapply(split(tmp, tmp$group),
                             function(x) list(divider, x)), recursive = F))
```